# IONIC 2 Build error: "ngc: Error: Error Cannot write file ...[myProject]/.tmp/[some folder]/*.d.ts"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I get build error when I launch a CLI: "ionic build android"

**The error applies to several file, all applying the same pattern:
"ngc: Error: Error Cannot write file '[myProjectName]/.tmp/[some more folder + a file with '.d.ts' extension]' because it would overwrite input file."**

Ionic version:

- Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v6.7.0

I've tried to launch a CLI: "npm install", and then CLI: "ionic add/rm/add platform android". Relaunched the build and still get the same error.

Any idea about what is going on? What's the matter with the ".tmp" folder?

**Some update**: The issue happens to have an existing thread [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/123) . At some point in the thread, it suggests to delete the "*.d.ts" files. It does the trick but it means that operation might have to be done manually again in the future, so a better solution are still pending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue.

Change your tsconfig.json to have

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks it works succesfuly, but I don't understand, **what would be the use to have declaration set to true then?** On the page regarding **declaration** on typescript doc, I did not find straight forward explanation. The compiler-options page (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) says: "Generates corresponding ‘.d.ts’ file. 
". When digging deeper about what is '.d.ts' file, it becomes abstract.